# How to drop database in Integration Testing mysql TypeOrm Nestjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs

I am using mysql as database, I searched on the internet and the methods I tried were not up to date. I want the db to reset itself in every test. But I couldn't find the appropriate method, can you help?

```
describe('Authentication System', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();
    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('if user already in database', async () => {
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send({name:"muti"})
      .expect(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
      .then((res) => {
        const { access_token } = res.body;
        expect(access_token).not.toBeDefined();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it on my end by using the DataSource object that TypeORM provides to do solve it.

Initialize the DataSource object like so:

```
const dataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DBHOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DBPORT),
  username: process.env.DBUSER,
  password: process.env.DBPASS,
  database: process.env.DBNAME,
  entities: [`Your Entity Classes`],
  synchronize: true,
});
```

Ensure that your loading the appropriate configuration into your app.module.ts file

Then you can use a `beforeAll` and `afterAll` test case to initailize and drop the databases respectively.

```
describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await dataSource.initialize();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('/ (GET)', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/')
      .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
      .expect('Hello World!');
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await dataSource.dropDatabase();
  });
});
```